# Adjust height of navbarPage() header in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to adapt the size/height of the navbarPage Menue since it is occupying a lot of space.

I tried working with some CSS style adaption but since I am new to that I am struggling a little bit.
This is how it looks at the moment:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMWac.jpg)

And this is the corresponding ui:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
navbarPage(
title = h4(style="text-align:center", "Man vs. Machine"),
tabPanel(h4(style="text-align:center","Voting"),
        tags$style("
             .col-sm-8 { /* radioButtons is a div class*/
               margin-top: 20px;
             }"),
fluidRow(column(12,h4("Click the Hydrograph you prefer?")))),
fluidRow(tableOutput("select")),
       tabPanel(h4(style="text-align:center","Results"),
                fluidRow(column(2, textOutput("value"))),
                fluidRow(column(2, textOutput("value2")))))))
```

Comment: Your `h4` tags are increasing the size -- are you interested in keeping the `h4`, but decreasing the margins around them?

Comment: Yes, I know that I changed the text size with h4 and yes changing the margins around would be my goal!

Comment: @JoeW. were you ever able to resolve this? adjusting the padding around the titles is proving difficult for me. also using header tags is giving me issues.